# improved formatting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have an HTML form that is a div in a bigger page:

```
<form action="send_form_email.php" method="post">
    <h4>E-mail</h4>
    <div class="border-stripes">
        <input type="email" class="textfield" name="email" placeholder="Your e-mail address" />
    </div>
    <h4>Message</h4>
    <div class="border-stripes">
        <textarea class="textarea" name="message" rows="3" placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and I have this php code

```
if ($_POST['submit']) {
    if ($email == false) {
        // ***Insert <p>invalid email address</p> above <h4>email</h4>***
    } else if (strlen(trim($_REQUEST['message'])) == 0) {
        // ***Insert <p>Send a Message</p> above <h4>email</h4>***
    } else if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $email)) {
        // ***Insert <p>Successfully sent</p> above <h4>email</h4>***
    }
}
```

My problem is that I don't know how to add that `extra paragraph` according to the `if statement`, and then I want the page to automatically scroll down to the form displaying the error.

For instance, if the email address was invalid, I want the page to be redirected to the form div and display above "Email" that the email address is invalid

Comment: use like `echo '<p>invalid email address</p> above <h4>email</h4>'` and for to scroll down use jquery .. Do research before simply asking..

Comment: I did research that's why im asking! I can't find the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Put your message into a variable for each if statement like this:

```
if ($_POST['submit']) {
  if ($email == false) {
     $msg = "<p>invalid email address</p>";
  } else if (strlen(trim($_REQUEST['message'])) == 0) {
     $msg = "<p>Send a Message</p>";
  } else if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $email)) {
     $msg = "<p>Successfully sent</p>";
  }else{
     $msg ="";
 }
}else{
   $msg = "";
}
```

And then echo your message above the email field:

```
<form action="send_form_email.php" method="post">
<?php echo $msg; ?>
<h4>E-mail</h4>
<div class="border-stripes">
    <input type="email" class="textfield" name="email" placeholder="Your e-mail address" />
</div>
<h4>Message</h4>
<div class="border-stripes">
    <textarea class="textarea" name="message" rows="3" placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: As for the scrolling down to the form after submitting look into jQuery scrollTop.  Something like $('body').scrollTop(position) should work

Comment: Jake, when the decision is being taken through the if statements, the page is being directed to a blank page with nothing displayed

Comment: Usually when a blank page is displayed with PHP it means there is an error in the code somewhere. Check that your not missing any  ;  and that brackets are being opened and closed properly.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from the problem you stated here is that -- you want to display error or success message if the post is submitted successfully or not.

For that you you can write both the code in same file `send_form_email.php` like as below.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST)) {
    if ($_POST['email'] == false) {
        $msg = "<p>invalid email address</p> above <h4>email</h4>";
    } else if (strlen(trim($_POST['message'])) == 0) {
        $msg = "Insert <p>Send a Message</p> above <h4>email</h4>";
    } else if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $email)) {
        $msg = "Insert <p>Successfully sent</p> above <h4>email</h4>";
    }
}
?>

<html>
  <head>
    <title> My First Form </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="send_form_email.php" method="post">
      <h4>E-mail</h4>
      <div class="border-stripes">
        <input type="email" class="textfield" name="email" placeholder="Your e-mail address" />
      </div>
      <h4>Message</h4>
      <div class="border-stripes">
        <textarea class="textarea" name="message" rows="3" placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
      </div>
      <br />
      <br />
      <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <div class="msg-box">
      <?php echo $msg ? $msg : ''; ?>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```